# Making all the characters in a string lowercase in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lowercase

Here is the thing. I am trying to convert a string in lowercase in Lua, but it's not working. I have done this

```
String = String:lower()
```

but it doesn't like it. I am sure that is the way to do it, I've seen it done before. A few sites suggest it might be a problem caused by a wrong version of the interpreter.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't like it"? What error message do you get, if any.

Comment: I mean it gives me this error:

    input:1: attempt to index global 'String' (a nil value)

I found out it is because the value String I was using was empty when it shouldn't. It is complicated, but I found out in the end, I don't need it in my code, so it's ok.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You're right, this is one of the ways to do it. It would only not work and throw errors if your "String" variable is not a string.

Personally, i usually prefer to use something like..

```
myString = string.lower(myString)
```

But its really the same as doing

```
myString = myString:lower()
```

assuming that myString is actually a string, however.

The "long" version has one advantage, it actually works if myString is a number, while the second one errors in that case.